# Universal Clearable textbox on html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textbox

I want to have clearable textbox on my web application. I got this working code.

**CSS**

```
.clearable {
    background: url(../Images/close.png) no-repeat right -10px center;
    transition: background 0.4s;
}

.clearable.x {
    background-position: right 10px center;
}

.clearable.onX {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(function ($) {
            function tog(v) { return v ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass'; }
            $(document).on('input', '.clearable', function () {
                $(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
            }).on('mousemove', '.x', function (e) {
                $(this)[tog(this.offsetWidth - 18 < e.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');
            }).on('click', '.onX', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('').change();
            });
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="clearable" type="text" />
```

Here's a sample **JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/h7fybLxn/3/

Is it possible for make it for all textboxes I have on my application?

Like having `input[type=text]`.

Comment: you would have to select all textbox, so like you do $('div') in jquery something like $('textboxvalue') would be sufficient. this isnt the correct way btw im just saying that something similar should work :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/h7fybLxn/4/

is this what you're after ?

Ive updated your fiddle so you clear all textboxes with the same class rather than selecting 'this'.

Instead of this :

```
$(this).removeClass('x onX').val('').change(); //btw keep this in if you just want to clear each textbox individually
```

I put this :

```
$('.clearable').removeClass('x onX').val('').change();
```

Also a change in your HTML so they have the same class :

```
<input class="clearable" type="text" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input class='clearable' type="text" /> <!-- I want on this textbox too -->
```